# Escape spaces when passing a file path to a command opened with cygstart

Tags: cygwin

## The Issue

When running the following command:

```
cygstart bash "/home/FirstName LastName/bin/script.sh"
```

The file path being passed to `bash` is getting cut off at the space, so I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: /home/FirstName: No such file or directory
```

### What I've tried:

1.

```
cygstart bash "/home/FirstName LastName/bin/script.sh"
```

2.

```
FILE_PATH="/home/FirstName LastName/bin/script.sh"
cygstart bash "$FILE_PATH"
```

3.

```
FILE_PATH="/home/FirstName LastName/bin/script.sh"
cygstart bash "${FILE_PATH}"
```

4.

```
FILE_PATH="/home/FirstName LastName/bin/script.sh"
cygstart bash ${FILE_PATH}
```

5.

```
FILE_PATH="/home/FirstName LastName/bin/script.sh"
MY_COMM=$(cygstart bash "$FILE_PATH")
eval $MY_COMM
```

Along with half a dozen other variations that I can't recall at the moment, including all of the above with a backslash to escape the space. The error is always the same.

**What am I missing, or is there even a way to solve this?**

UPDATE: The reason I am using `cygstart` in this case is to take advantage of it's `--action=runas` option. The script I am calling renames a file, but it has to be run with admin privileges to do so. The idea is that I can just call the script and then enter in the appropriate credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a test, I created a script in `~/Test Dir/test.sh`.  Here's what worked for me:

```
cygstart bash \"/home/cxw/Test\ Dir/test.sh\"
```

The `\"` at the beginning and end are freestanding double-quotes, which will wrap what's between them to keep it together as one argument.

The issue is that the parameters are being put into the Windows [ShellExecute function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx), which winds up splitting args at whitespace.  To see the exact command being run, use `cygstart -v`.

The result of the above is a `ShellExecute` call like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "(null)", "bash", ""/home/cxw/Test Dir/test.sh"", "(null)", 1)
```

Note the paired double-quotes: the outer quotes are printed by `cygstart -v`, and the inner are the `\"` to keep the script name together.

I listed `/home/cxw` instead of `~` because `~` didn't work for me.  You can use `cygpath -a` to get absolute paths if you need them.

Comment: Holy Crabst! I knew it had to do with escaping something but, for the life of me, I couldn't figure out what. Thanks a ton! Especially for the additional information on what was going on.